How do I programmatically access the Description field of MP4 metadata?
I'd like to write an AppleScript that extracts the metadata from the "Description" field in .mp4 files. I usually do this manually opening VLC > Media Information > General. On "Description" field is where the data that I need resides.
Would you have a suggestion on how this field can be accessed either using MacOs mdls or AppleScript (Automator)? (without having to use VLC) I'm sure this info it stored on some header of the .mp4 file but am unable to retrieve it.


It look like VLC saves its "Description" in Exif comment metadata, which would be buried in the file and not in extended attributes or Spotlight metadata.  Exif is a standard, but neither Apple nor AppleScript have anything built-in to manipulate it, although some applications may provide importers for Spotlight.  If you don't want to dig into it yourself, you would need to use a third-party utility such as ExifTool.
